# Android studio TCPClient can't send data

Tags: java, android, sockets, printwriter

I made a TCP/IP app that needs to send data to a phone. The send function works just fine when I'm associating it with a button or any asynctask, but when I try to send a letter right when an activity is created (in the `onCreate` method), it just doesn't work. The phone doesn't receive anything. Here's the code for sending:

```
if (mTcpClient != null) {
    mTcpClient.sendMessage("m");
}
```

Now here's what's in sendMessage:

```
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

The exact same code works when I copy paste it into a button (`onclicklistener`) or an asynctask. What could be the problem?

Comment: That code only works in an AsyncTask or thread. Moreover you did not explain what happens instead if it fails. Please remove Android studio from your post. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: So what should I do to make it work in onCreate?  Nothing happens when it fails. The activity starts without issue, but the letter doesn't get sent. Im making the app in android studio, hence the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing if an error has been detected, yet you never report the error.

In general you should not use `PrintWriter` over a network, because it swallows exceptions you need to know about. Use `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to java and do not understand. Does making it bufferedwriter enable it to send data via onCreate? I use a seperate tcp client class, and then access it through an object created in the activity. Changing printwriter to bufferedwriter is giving a lot of unhandled exception errors.